# draw a line between two boxes which are draggable in selenium webdriver using Java code

Tags: java, jquery, selenium

I am working on selenium web driver and my Appliction does not support css selector. In my application, I have Flowchart page where I need to add FlowChart. I have drag and drop two rectangle boxes in the flowchart page where each rectangle boxes has four arrows.
Use one of the arrows from the source rectangle box should connect to the top arrow of the destination rectangle box. I dont know how to connect both the boxes. Also, if we drag one of the arrows from the source to target point, it will draw a line between the two.

I tried in many ways but not able to connect and draw a line between two boxes. I should write the code in Java only. Pls help.

Also, i observed that when i try to find the co-ordinates of the arrows of two different rectangle boxes, then it shows the same co-ordinates i,e

location of the two arrows (source and target) shows same co-ordiantes (-9317, -9973)
(-9317, -9973)

why it is showing Negative x and y points. Pls reply me to write the code in JAVA only since I am using JAVA in my program
I tried with the below code to draw a line between two flowchart boxes in JAVA - using selenium Webdriver

```
WebElement selectarrow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//circle[@cx='10']"));
        System.out.println(selectarrow.getLocation()); 

 Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(selectarrow, 250, 50)  
                    .clickAndHold()
                    .moveByOffset(250,50)
                    .moveByOffset(270,110)
                    .release()
                    .build();
          drawAction.perform();
```

to draw line using select arrow as the source point and 250,50 as the destination point of the area.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Here, we don't write code for you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried with the below code to draw a line between two flowchart boxes in JAVA - using selenium webdriverWebElement selectarrow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//circle[@cx='10']"));
   System.out.println(selectarrow.getLocation());

Comment: That code doesn't make a lot of sense without seeing the HTML. Also, I can't see anything wrong with the code. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I also don't understand how you want to draw lines with Selenium. Selenium doesn't draw. You can use Selenium can only send events to a web page to simulate a user.

Comment: We should draw using Java code. If I know, i will paste the code here.

Comment: I have edited my question more briefly with the code what i used. Pls gothrough the code and try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's get some terminology straight: Java and Selenium don't draw anything. Java is used to execute the Selenium code. Selenium just sends events to the browser.

The main problem with Selenium is that you're doing keyhole surgery: There is little feedback when something goes wrong, it's hard to see what you're doing and even when everything looks fine, it can still break. Keep that in mind.

What your code is doing: You are creating a series of mouse click and drag events, specifically:

- go to 250, 50 relative to the top/left corner of `selectarrow`
- Click and hold
- go 250 right and 50 down
- go 270 right and 110 down
- let go of the left mouse button

This isn't what you described that you want to do. The code to do what you describe looks like:

```
Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(selectarrow, 0, 0)  
                .clickAndHold()
                .moveByOffset(250,50)
                .release()
                .build();
drawAction.perform();
```

Note that you may want to use `5,5` instead of `0,0` to make sure you're inside the element. But when you do, you may have to modify `moveByOffset()` as well or the final point might be off.

Comment: Thanks for your Detailed Explanation. I tried with the code which draws a line between two rectangular boxes.

Answer (score -1):

To draw the line between two boxes,

```
WebElement segmentPB = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dojoUnique3 > img"));
                (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDropBy(segmentPB,300, 175).perform();

                 WebElement droppedSegmentBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Flowchart > div:nth-child(3) > svg > g:nth-child(2) > g:nth-child(2) > g:nth-child(2) > g > g:nth-child(2) > g:nth-child(1) > image:nth-child(1)"));
                 System.out.println(droppedSegmentBox.getLocation());   

                Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                builder.moveToElement(droppedSelectBox).perform();

                droppedSelectBox.click();

                WebElement selectArrow = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Flowchart > div:nth-child(3) > svg > g:nth-child(2) > g:nth-child(3) > g:nth-child(2) > g:nth-child(4) > g > g:nth-child(3) > g > g > path:nth-child(2)"));

                System.out.println(selectArrow.getLocation());  
                // To draw the line between Two Process Boxes
                (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(selectArrow, droppedSegmentBox).build().perform();
```

Comment: Yes ,this is the code solved my problem, i have been keep trying with this code but with small mistake...i,e movetoElement(droppedSelectBox).perform was missed and my team found that and rectified.